# Using Articles on Introducing a Person

Tags: articles

While learning English, I often found myself embarrassed in the erratic usage of English articles. Would you mind if I ask a question about it?

When we're introducing a person in an article, which one should I use between:

> "Tom Cruise, **an American actor** well known for ..."

and

> "Tom Cruise, **American actor** well ..."?

Also, I would like to know should I always put "the" in the following sentence:

> "Barack Obama is **the** 44th President of the United States"

or can I just leave the sentence without it.

If there was a point I used incorrect English, feel free to fix it. I would really appreciate your answer.

Comment: It can depend on context, level of formality required etc. But I think you would find more help for things like this on our sister site *English Language, Learners*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Tom Cruise, American actor well..." is more common for making a short statement or with a list of other of his attributes, character etc to audience who already probably know about him. Best used with a coma:-
"Tom Cruise, American actor well..."
Its the same for "Barack Obama, 44th President of the United States"

Using 'the' is expecting a more detailed discussion and mostly likely to an audience who may not know much about him.